# Schengeni Allamok

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, hungary

I have applied for a Schengen multiple entry visa from Hungary in conference (academic) category short term visa.

What I received is a Schengeni Allamok, type-C, valid for 14 days, single entry, and on remark its written that: konfercian valo reszvetel/conference VIS.

Is there any problem if I follow the itinerary
India->Vienna->Budapest(conference venue)->Paris(by flight)-> Vienna->India.

Comment: The answer would be either "probably not" or "certainly not," depending on the itinerary you presented in your visa application.

Comment: Your comment mentions a change of itinerary. If this is the issue, please edit the message and add both itineraries - the one you presented in the application and the one you intend to follow. @JanDoggen - I'm not sure your edit explains the issue correctly. It seems like he intended to return directly from Paris, and now wants to add Vienna.

Comment: @ugoren Yeah, missed that. Edited out again. Let the OP fix it properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an allowed itinerary, and you applied at the correct embassy.

At Vienna airport, you may be asked for your onward ticket to Budapest and possibly proof of the conference, so bring that documentation.